# Advise: Looking for a job and they request the name of my supervisor?

Tags: job-search, references

I finished my PhD but I filed a complaint against my supervisors and one of them is the Head of the Department. I received an official apology letter from the university about my poor experience as a PhD student and for the wrong informations they stated about me during my PhD.

My relationship with my supervisors ended up on a bad term, they know their mistakes but I exposed them to the university.
Now, I am looking for a job and getting a reference letter is not an issue.
The issue is they sometimes ask for my supervisor name and I do not want to give them any of their name. 
Any suggestions of how to overcome that?

P.S. the supervisors are in UK and the job are world wide.

Comment: I thought of doing that too, but I was afraid the question will come during the interview

Comment: Don't give them the names, and explain why, email through any documents you've got. It should only bother you for the first job.

Comment: @AllenZhang Thank you for your advise

Comment: *getting a reference letter is not an issue* Who are you getting this reference letter from, and why can you not give them as a reference?

Comment: @Smock a reference letter can be provided by my colleagues or my former supervisor during MSc. So, it is not an issue for me to get a reference letter. I had a super evil supervisors during my PhD and that is why the university apologised for my poor experience as a PhD students. That is why I do not want to give my PhD's supervisors name because they are super evil

Comment: @user8670370 I meant, why could you not just give your former supervisor as a referee

Comment: @Smock as I explained. My supervisors made my life is a living hell. They tried to destroy me by not letting me attend conferences or publishing my work.Because my research was really good, the primary supervisor wanted to publish my work in his own name. He told me infront of teh second supervisor I have to chose between my PhD and between publishing a paper. My third supervisor know about this but he took their sides because they are his colleague and they will protect him the same way he protected them. So, does that answer your question?

Comment: @Smock , also I do not trust them anymore. I filed the complaint and showed everything and the university just apologised without taking any actions against them.

Comment: @user8670370 So your former MSc supervisor is also evil and untrustworthy?

Comment: @Smock, no. My MSc supervisor was really good and we have a very good realtionship. It has been 10 years now and he still write recommendations for me. He has a very good reputation in the oil company and also has lots of publication. But the issue is when I apply for a job they request the name of my PhD supervisor not my MSC

Comment: @user8670370 Ahh so it's just too long ago then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From everyone comments I can conclude the best way is not to provide their name at all and avoid mentioning their names during the interview. 
Their names come in my thesis and in my publications. However, that does not mean it is the end of teh world. I graduated and lost contact with them. I cannot force them to write a reference letter for me and I do not trust they will not do anything to damage my reputation like what they did when I was in university. 
Since the job application asks for any of tehir names, I should just leave it blank and defend my decision I provided a reference letter.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on the country. In the USA: Give them the name. Tell the supervisor, and tell them that you will hold them responsible if they damage your prospects.

As the supervisor, I would be very reluctant to say anything bad, especially if you got a letter from the university apologising for the supervisors behaviour.

Comment: The apology was for their behaviour and the wrong information they stated about me. The supervisors are in UK and I cannot give their name without their consent.

Comment: @gnasher Not a good idea. If OP gives the names, superviser will tell on request they are unable to submit a reference. You cannot hold them accountable for that, but it's damaging nonetheless. You cannot force them to write a glowing reference or a reference at all.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs you are right. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Approach the supervisor and ask for a reference.

Be polite.

Your supervisor will either say yes or no. Most likely yes. It would be very unusual for someone to give a poor reference in the UK because companies (and universities) are worried about the possibility of being pursued in court for defamation or similar.

Comment: Thank you. I already did sent him an email but he did not reply which means he does not want to be involved.

Comment: Besides, he now has an experience of doing most stuff without leaving a trace to him like emails or word documents. That is how I filed the complaint in the first place by using documents against him and how I know he will do unethical things.